# The Heide Knight in the Forest of Fallen Giants will not spawn

Tags: dark-souls-2

I have not seen the knight in the forest of fallen giants that i have read about.Does anyone know why the white knight is not spawning under the tree for me? Is there something i can do?

Comment: Can you take a screenshot?  Maybe you're in the wrong place?

Comment: im not able to take a screenshot but it is the tree surrounded by hollows with one up top throwing fire bombs. the white gate is to the left of the tree when you finish climbing the latter up to the grotto

Comment: https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3395/13083415484_4104d08e91_o.jpg

Comment: that is where he should be i guess but i have not seen him. i restarted a new character and still could not get him to spawn for me

Comment: Weird, that's the place...  I will see what I can find out.

Comment: Thank you i would appreciate that ive been looking all over for an answer haha.

Comment: Are you playing the Scholar of the First Sin version?

Answer (score 5):

If you are playing the Original DS II than there is a Heide Knight under that tree. But if you play Scholar of the First Sin - which is the same game except some changes and all DLC's included there is *no* Heide Knight. They moved them to a different location.

Comment: Also, in the original version they don't respawn until the next playthrough (or if you use a bonfire ascetic), in Scholar of the first Sin they do respawn, just like other enemies. There are also quite a lot while the original had like 3 in the entire game.